# How can I loop through a firebase collection and add a unique color to each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase

I am trying to loop through user profiles and assign a unique color to each person. Here is what I have so far:

Update: I am able to loop through $scope.profiles and access each profile individually. I cannot figure out how to add a unique color from the colors array to each profile.

```
 var colors  = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'orange', 'teal', 'violet', 'burgandy', 'brown', 'pink'];

 var obj = $firebase(new Firebase('https://demo.firebaseio.com/' + team + '/profiles')).$asObject();

 obj.$loaded().then(function() {
  var i = 0;
    angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
      //how do I add a color from the colors array?
      value.$add(colors[i++]);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var ind = 0;

$.each($scope.profiles, function (i, e){
  if (e && e.username){
      e.colour = colors[ind++]
  }
});
```

**Update**

If `$scope.profiles` is a promise something like this might work:

```
var ind = 0;

$.when($scope.profiles).done(function(obj){
    $.each(obj, function (i, e){
        if (e && e.username){
            e.colour = colors[ind++]
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is the exact solution that worked.**

```
// to take an action after the data loads, use $loaded() promise
     $scope.profiles.$loaded().then(function() {
       var i = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.profiles, function(value, key, profile) {
          value.color = colors[i++];
          profile.$save();
        });
     });
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in setting the color in firebase. I updated it to an angular.forEach. The problem is at least somewhat related to $scope.profiles being a promise.

Comment: Is there an angularjs equivalent to .when. I can try $loaded?

Comment: I modified it to this:     $scope.profiles.$loaded().then(function(obj){
      angular.forEach(obj, function (i, e){
          if (e && e.username){
              e.colour = colors[ind++];
          }
      });
    }); but that doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to dig into it to figure out why but it's unclear at the moment.

Comment: @EmptyPockets Have a look at https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/377 There's code as `var obj = $firebase(new Firebase(URL)).$asObject();

   
     obj.$loaded().then(function() {`

Comment: Thank you @artm that is really close. Working on tweaking it now. Just need to one of the colors from the colors array to each profile.

Comment: @EmptyPockets The easieast for that might be using that `var ind = 0` variable inside the loop. If you have more profiles than colours you can do `e.colour = colors[(ind++) % colors.length]`